# Nativescript - how to run a plugin demo

Tags: nativescript

I cloned the nativescript-google-maps-sdk plugin

and would like to run the app in the 'demo' folder.

How do I do that?

I went into the demo folder and typed `tns build iOS`

worked fine and then

`tns run iOS`

I got error

`Could not find module 'nativescript-google-maps-sdk'`

This is the error at the end:

`file:///app/main-page.js:3:25: JS ERROR Error: Could not find module 'nativescript-google-maps-sdk'. Computed path '/Users/asrock/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2462B1E0-F0D5-4EC5-B31B-1A5AE8CACC74/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DD86BB36-6F11-437C-B6CA-9F936478E87D/demo.app/app/tns_modules/nativescript-google-maps-sdk'.`

It seems like it's looking for the google sdk under /tns_modules instead of /node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the demo app doesn't know where to find the plugin. You may need something along the lines of the `plugin.prepare` or the `plugin.link` or possibly `link` then `prepare` could be useful depending on how you have it setup. Don't forget the `tsc` at the top modifies all calls to `npm run tsc`. Also, don't forget to replace `<<<<YOUR-PLUGIN-NAME>>>>` with your actual plugin name which is usually something like `nativescript-volume`.

```
// In the official plugin seed src/package.json
// https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed

"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc -skipLibCheck",
    "build": "npm i && tsc",
    "postclone": "npm i && node scripts/postclone.js && cd ../demo && npm i && cd ../src && npm run plugin.link",
    "test.android": "npm i && npm run tsc && npm run tslint && cd ../demo && tns build android && tns test android --justlaunch",
    "test.ios": "npm i && npm run tsc && npm run tslint && cd ../demo && tns build ios && tns test ios --justlaunch",
    "tslint": "cd .. && tslint \"**/*.ts\" --config tslint.json --exclude \"**/node_modules/**\"",
    "plugin.link": "npm link && cd ../demo && npm link <<<<YOUR-PLUGIN-NAME>>>> && cd ../src",
    "plugin.tscwatch": "npm run tsc -- -w",
    "demo.ios": "npm i && npm run tsc && cd ../demo && tns run ios --syncAllFiles",
    "demo.android": "npm i && npm run tsc && cd ../demo && tns run android --syncAllFiles",
    "demo.reset": "cd ../demo && rimraf platforms",
    "plugin.prepare": "npm run tsc && cd ../demo && tns plugin remove <<<<YOUR-PLUGIN-NAME>>>> && tns plugin add ../src",
    "clean": "cd ../demo && rimraf hooks node_modules platforms && cd ../src && rimraf node_modules && npm run plugin.link",
    "ci.tslint": "npm i && tslint '**/*.ts' --config '../tslint.json' --exclude '**/node_modules/**'"
},
```

Comment: Still trying to get the demo folder for nativescript-google-maps-sdk to run. I do a cd into the demo folder and tns run iOS and it seems to create the app and send to the simulator but it crashes on startup. I get the same error as in my OP.

Comment: Apologies for not having seen this sooner... I'm going to attempt to run the demo and see if I get the same.

Comment: I was unable to even get it to build. :-/ So I'm not sure what to tell you. It seems that it's not copying all the files... have you tried a `tns run ios --syncAllFiles` just to see if maybe it's skipping something?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run demo.android
npm run demo.ios
```

respectively from the src folder should run the demo app with the plugin...